# How do I return a promise in a redux action dispatch call so I can chain .then blocks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise

I am creating an app using react-native and redux. My app should send a request to a firebase rest api to get back a user's todo's. In my react-native app, I get this response through a redux function that is passed in the connect part of the react-native components. I would like to chain a .then block right after I call my function.

I have tried creating a promise and returning that in my action but it automatically resolves to an error when chaining the .then / .catch
I have also tried doing the same without creating a promise.

Here is my action:

```
export const fetchHomework = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch(uiStartLoading());
      dispatch(uiStartFetchingHomework());
      dispatch(authGetToken())
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(errHandler(err))
      })
      .then(token => {
        const uid = getState().userid;

        fetch(restAPI)
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(errHandler(err));
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({
            type : 'SET_HOMEWORK_FOR_AGENDA',
            homework : response
          })
          dispatch(uiStopLoading());
          dispatch(uiStopFetchingHomework());
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(errHandler(err));
          dispatch(uiStopLoading());
          dispatch(uiStopFetchingHomework());
        })

      })
      dispatch(uiStopLoading());
      dispatch(uiStopFetchingHomework());
  }
}
```

Note: rest api is replaced with the url of the rest api
And here is where I fetch this data:

```
this.setState({refreshing: true});
this.props.retrieveHomework();
this.setState({refreshing: false, firebaseItems : this.props.homework});
this.loadItems(this.state.selectedDay);
```

(This is called in a function when refreshing)

I expected that when I chain a .then block after retrieveHomework, the then block would wait for the function to finish and then run the code inside, but this is not what is happening. What is happening is it either skips the then blocks or throws an error that the catch block catches.

Edit:
this.props.retrieveHomework is a function that points to the async action since I am using redux thunk.

Comment: am I correct `props.retrieveHomework` refers to `fetchHomework` async action dispatcher? is `redux-thunk` used?

Comment: @skyboyer yes you’re correct. I’ll add that into my question for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all of the code you want to wait to run into the `.then`:

```
this.props.retrieveHomework()
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({refreshing: false, firebaseItems : this.props.homework});
    this.loadItems(this.state.selectedDay); // If this is async, you need to `return` it here as well
  });
```

Comment: Hey Matt. This did happen to work but presented another problem. Since I’m using redux thunk which is asynchronous, my action calls a sync function to set the data in the state and the async function returns before the sync function finishes. This means that when I call the .then I’m not getting an updated state since the sync function which sets it hasn’t finished. How can I make sure my sync function returns before returning my async function/ calling .then?

Comment: The thing is, `React.Component#setState` is also asynchronous. This is why it's recommended to call it with function as the first argument, like `this.setState(prevState => newState)`, which by the way should solve the problem of the execution order.

Comment: @rml I do happen to understand that but I think my question was confusing since I didn't provide the code. What I meant is that I call a reducer to set my state inside of the async dispatch and that reducer doesn't finish before the async call does so it doesn't update the state in time. How do I make it so my async function doesn't return until I set my state?

Comment: I'd probably begin rethinking the whole state management around this problem if it is so prone to race condition.  Did you think of wrapping the whole store update into a new Promise and only update component state when this promise resolves?

Comment: I think what @rml is suggesting is this: `this.setState({refreshing: false, firebaseItems : this.props.homework}, () => this.loadItems(this.state.selectedDay));` While `setState` does indeed take a callback function or an object as its first param, you only need to use the callback if you are references `this.state` in the new state values. `setState` also takes a second argument, which is a function to run _after_ `setState` has completed, because as @rml noted, `setState` is async itself

Comment: Okay I understand that. I've done a bit more debugging and it showed that my .then block is actually called before my prop action is called. I connect my prop through a mapDispatchToProps function containing:    retrieveHomework : () => dispatch(fetchHomework())              And then I call it within my code but the .then block on retrieveHomework fires before the fetchHomework() for some odd reason.

Comment: Can you update your code in the question with the example please? Also please remove all of the `dispatch`es and such that are unrelated to this problem to make the code easier to reason about

Comment: https://github.com/2021debaisen/FetchingExample/tree/master is the link to updated github code. Should contain all code that is run during this example